# No aplication.js in http node module

Tags: react-native, node-modules, metro-bundler

When I try to run my react-native app on ios or android, the Metro Bundler raises an error saying that I dont have `http` module installed.

I have tryed `npm react-native install http` and it is installed correctly but when I upload the app raises me this error:

error: bundling failed: Error: While trying to resolve module `http` from file `/node_modules/express/lib/application.js`, the package `node_modules/http/package.json` was successfully found. However, this package itself specifies a `main` module field that could not be resolved (`node_modules/http/index.js`.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I just figured out why I had this error. I was trying to use the variable styles the wrong way

Comment: Yo I'm having the same issue. what do you mean by that?

Comment: Where was this Styles variables? I found your other post where you talk about Style=>Styles, my Styles is called Styles as it should.

Comment: @KornilovRuslan I was making a mistake between styles variable and style prop of components. Check all your code so that you dont mistake them. A basic explanation can be found here https://reactnative.dev/docs/style

Comment: @Imanol can you please share the example or GitHub repo link it will help us.Actually i want to run Node.js inside React Native, so i'm facing this error.